# Слово "осина"

Tags: этимология

Подумалось, а от какого слова происходит "осина": *осень, осенять, синий* или еще что-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По Фасмеру: 
Осина, Ближайшая этимология: Укр. Осина, Осика, др.-русск. Осина, болг. Осика (Младенов 388), чеш. диал. оsа, osina, слвц. osika, польск. оsа, osina, в.-луж. wоsа, wоsуnа, п.-луж. wоsа, wosа ***"серебристый тополь"***  наряду с болг. Ясика "осина", сербохорв. jа°сиґка, словен. jasiґka, jesiґka; см. Розвадовский, RS 7, 20. Дальнейшая этимология: Праслав. *орsа родственно лит. a~pu«e†, арu«i°s "осина", вост.-лит. e~pu«e† "черный тополь", лтш. арsе "осина", др.-прусск. аbsе, д.-в.-н., др.-сакс. аsра "осина" (в фонетическом отношении ср. Осаґ: нов.-в.-н. Wеsре -- то же); см. Траутман, Арr. Sprd. 295; ВSW 11 и сл.; Бернекер 1, 31 и сл.; М.--Э. 1, 118; Бецценбергер, GGA, 1885, стр. 920; В. Шульце, KZ 45, 288; Педерсен, IF 5, 57. Сомнительна связь с греч. Ґsprij, Ґsproj "бесплодная порода дуба", Ўsp…j "щит, защита, ограда" (Хоопс, Waldb. 122; Reall. 1, 132 и сл.; Шрадер--Неринг, 1, 272; см. Гофман, Gr. Wb. 26) или с греч. ЎpellТn † A‡geiroj, У ™sti EЌdoj Dљndrou (Гесихий); ср. Шпехт 60. Но это слово должно было быть более широко распространено в и.-е., потому что алт., тел., леб. арsаk, тоб. аwsаk "тополь", чув. еЁvеЁs "осина" представляют стар. заимствование из какого-то и.-е. (вост.) языка (иранск., по мнению Хоопса (там же), арм., по мнению Педерсена (KZ 39, 462), Лидена (IF 18, 491)).

Answer (score 0):

Надо продолжить, поскольку дана лишь очевидная родственная этимология, объяснения исходного происхождения нет.
После этого текста у Фасмера отслеживается связь с пралавянскими корнями (но не более) и деляается вывод о древнем заимствовании из каких-то восточных (иранских или тюркских).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!